# PopUp window shows IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, runtime-error, popupwindow, illegalstateexception

I'm new to android. I wanna print a message(using Log.i) when the button is pressed in popup window but it exit & shows

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method deletemtd(View)
> in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined
> on view class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton with
> id 'button'

### My onclick method coding

```
    public void onButtonShowPopupWindowClick(View view) {

    // inflate the layout of the popup window
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_output_calculation, null);

    // create the popup window
    int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    boolean focusable = true; // lets taps outside the popup also dismiss it
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);

    // show the popup window
    // which view you pass in doesn't matter, it is only used for the window tolken
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    // dismiss the popup window when touched
    popupView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

### popup layout's `activity_output_calculation.xml` code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/myRED"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Output_calculation">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="deletemtd"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### Java code of popup

```
public class Output_calculation extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_output_calculation);
    }

    public void deletemtd(View view) {
        Log.i("tag nema", "deletemtd:");
    }
}
```

I wanna print this log message in run console when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout you use to set view of activity and popup are same but, **they are different view instances**, for the view set to the activity you have `deletemtd` in the activity code. **But when you inflated the xml to a view for showing it in the popup at that place there is no `deletemtd` method.**, what you must do is set an explicit listener to that view.

```
 public void onButtonShowPopupWindowClick(View view) {

    // inflate the layout of the popup window
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_output_calculation, null);

    // create the popup window
    int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    boolean focusable = true; // lets taps outside the popup also dismiss it
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);
     popupView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(null);
     //or a listener
    popupView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(v->{/*your task here*/});
    // show the popup window
    // which view you pass in doesn't matter, it is only used for the window tolken
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    // dismiss the popup window when touched
    popupView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Sorry @rahat. It return 'NullPointerException' at `view.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(v->{
            Log.i("aaa", "onButtonShowPopupWindowClick:ssss");
        });`

Comment: No need to be Sorry, It was a bug, instead of `view` it should be `popupView`.